# Format-number() not working in calculated column

Tags: workflow, infopath, xslt

**CASE**:

I'm using a Workflow in a huge process, one of which is to set an Infopath column to be incremental. However, this incremented column value has to be in a certain format and cannot be done in Designer as formatting it there doesn't effect the data itself (That will be used later in Infopath / Workflows).

**QUESTION**:

So, anyway to get a calculated column that has a formatted number ("000")? From my understanding, XSLT functions cannot be used in a calculated column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the TEXT function

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/text-function-HA001161083.aspx